# OpenID discontinuation, but inability to log on any other way

Tags: support, accounts, duplicate-accounts

So today I remembered [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647) and decided to give it a try to see if I could log on with my email address as opposed to the OpenID provider I had connected to my account.

Bad mistake.

BTW: the reason I am posting this here instead of on `meta.stackexchange.com` is because I now have a fresh account there (which I *never* intended!) with 1 reputation point, which is below the minimum to post there. So in essence if someone decides to migrate this question I'll be unable to comment, respond or whatever. I used to have an account there that had reputation somewhere in the 360s.

First thing was to log out of all Stack Exchange sites and check the check box for doing that on all devices.

The OpenID provider I had connected is one that I am running all by myself on my own server using [SimpleID](http://simpleid.koinic.net/).

I used to have an email address connected to that same account and I still have previous correspondence from various Stack Exchange sites in said mailbox. At some point, for example, I was offered moderator on one of the beta sites; those mails still exist. Alas, the "forgot?" link was apparently the worst choice I could have made. It caused the creation of the fresh account on `meta.stackexchange.com` for no good reason.

I have no idea how to proceed without further messing up things. When I try the https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery link or similar links, I see a confirmation that the email with the recovery link has been sent:

[image: recovery confirmation]

When I then click the recovery link, I get to set a password and next thing I see this:

[image: Confirm new login]

Alas, the first time I confirmed that, I ended up with a fresh account with no reputation on `meta.stackexchange.com`.

How do I get out of this without further damage?

At this time an attempt to log on with anything but my registered OpenID provider yields rather surprising results. (NB: I intentionally blurred out the email addresses.)

---

It almost appears as if I now have somehow "split" the account and each and every one of the Stack Exchange sites now has an independent account, even though I used to be active with this very account on several of them.

To give you an example, after logging in with OpenID on Stack Overflow and then switching sites to `reverseengineering.stackexchange.com`, I am offered "Join this community" although the menu I used to switch sites showed me the reputation value:

[image: switching sites]

Comment: @wizzwizz4: well, given that I _have_ to act, seeing as OpenID is going to be discontinued, I don't know how I could have avoided this.

Comment: I'd have spun up a test account, or used an existing one if I had one. I've seen several of these sorts of posts on metas. Perhaps it should be updated to "Never experiment with authentication on your main account." instead.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: as the linked post points out it is no longer possible to register OpenID for new accounts, so I was out of luck either way.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Really? What makes you think that OpenID system will be going away?

Comment: @NoBugs: well, unless I and dozens others misunderstood it: [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ends-on-july-1-2018).

Comment: @0xC0000022L I didn't see that... how sad :/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Generally, you just use the contact us link in the footer and ask us to help you, but I've already merged the credential and you should be able to use it properly now. There were some simple oddities in your account that just prevented the automated systems from working as they would normally, and it just needed a real person to say "yes, they're the same person."

Comment: Oh, apologies. I thought this was the right method due to [tag:support]. Will use the contact form next time. Thanks for your manual intervention.

Comment: The community here can help you with a *lot* of the features of our sites. But something related to your account or credentials is usually something only staff can help you with.

Comment: This sounds like it is going to be a real hassle for you guys to possibly have to do this for thousands of accounts. Is there no way you could put together some kind of template for yourselves so that users can associate their accounts during the transition? I can see this becoming overwhelming.

Comment: @ouflak For the vast majority of users, this will work automatically and they won't need assistance from us. This particular account had oddities that are probably only present on less than .001% of accounts.

Comment: *shrug* Ok. It's not me who has to deal with any 'oddities'. Maybe this was just a fluke instead of a foreshadowing....

Comment: @animuson: I feel special now ;)